# How to set default thumbnail for broken remote server urls in Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

We have 4000 remote server thumbnail urls as `dp_video_poster` meta key in `wp_postmeta` in our wordpress database.

Those 4000 urls are all broken (404 not found) on remote server. We want to set default thumbnail for those broken ones on our own server.
How can we do it by adding php code into one of our wordpress files?

Comment: Do you want to replace them permanently with your default, or should this be a "If image not found display fallback, may be there later" thing?

Comment: Which one is more better? "If image not found display fallback, may be there later" thing looks great if its better.

Comment: That is your decision. Is it possible these broken images may be working in the near future?

Comment: No not possible in the future. Then I'd need to permanently put a default thumbnail url on our server.

Comment: Do you have a Query to determine which images are broken (e.g. they all begin with `/images/broken/`) or is this an estimation (e.g. by looking at a page displaying all images and checking the 404-Count in the console)?

Comment: Yes I have the urls but they are all different structured like in different folders and different file names in remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all of the broken images with the path to your thumbnail, there shouldn't be the need to implement PHP code.
First, get your broken urls:

```sql
SELECT id FROM imageTable WHERE ... #For the broken URLs
```

Then you can run an `UPDATE` statement to replace the invalid URLs with your placeholder-URL:

```sql
UPDATE imageTable SET url = :placeholderUrl
  WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM imageTable WHERE ... #Conditions for broken URLs
  )
```

Using this query, all of your broken URLs are now replaced with the value of `:placeholderUrl`. I suggest to create a backup beforehand, you never know what a little mistake might cause.

Comment: In wordpress database We have these thumbs as url links:

1st example:

http://thumb-v.xhcdn.com/t/170/1_6933170.jpg
2nd example:

https://thumb-v.xhcdn.com/t/325/200/3_8168325.jpg
Others are similar. There are over 2000+ urls are exist in the database like above. However the entire database have 15000 urls different than these urls. So I don't want to change all of them just the above structured ones.

I'd like to change/replace these multiple urls with one specific url like this:

http://example.com/lockedthumb.jpg
How to do this?

Comment: provide a structure which applies to these urls, e.g. `v.xhcdn.com/t/<number>/<number>/someImageName.jpg`

Comment: Sorry but it looks very advanced for me. Can you show me at least an example on how to do it?